# Where do docs explain why "git log" output differs based on checked-out branch?

Tags: git, git-log

The output from `git log` is different based on what branch I currently have checked-out.  Where in the git documentation does it explain this behavior?

I looked at `git log --help` and `git rev-list --help` but don't see anything explaining the that `git log` is context-sensitive based on which branch I have checked-out.

EDIT:
I had read the following section that @max and @James mentioned, and it's clear what happens when one of the commits is omitted and `..` is specified.  But it's ambiguous what happens when both commits are omitted. And it's also ambiguous when one commit is omitted and the `..` is omitted:

> <since>..<until>
>
> Show only commits between the named two commits.
>   When either <since> or <until> is omitted, it defaults to HEAD, i.e. the tip of
>   the current branch.

So, for example, the following would be equivalent:
`git log master..`  is equivalent to:
`git log master..HEAD`

`git log ..master` is equivalent to:
`git log HEAD..master`

But, if **both** <since> and <until> are omitted, then what?
`git log` is **NOT** equivalent to:
`git log HEAD..HEAD`

So what is `git log` equivalent to in the <since>..<until> format?

And if only one commit is listed, but not `..`, then what?
`git log foo` equivalent to:
`git log foo..HEAD` or
`git log HEAD..foo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git log has an implied argument HEAD so when you do

> git log

you are actually doing

> git log HEAD

which means you will get the log from the tip of the current branch

From [Git Log Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for since..until options

> Show only commits between the named two commits. When either  or  is >omitted, **it defaults to HEAD**, i.e. the tip of the current branch. For a more complete >list of ways to spell  and , see gitrevisions(7).

As per **updated question** the following should explain all the situations you stated

From [Git Revisions](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html)

> For example, origin.. is a shorthand for origin..HEAD and asks "What did I do since I >forked from the origin branch?" Similarly, ..origin is a shorthand for HEAD..origin and >asks "What did the origin do since I forked from them?" Note that .. would mean >HEAD..HEAD which is an empty range that is both reachable and unreachable from HEAD.

If .. is omitted then it is just

```
git log <rev>
```

which include commits that are reachable from (i.e. ancestors of) rev.
This is explained in [git-rev-list](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) who’s options are applicable to git-log as stated in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

One of the first sections of [git-log man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

> <since>..<until>
>
> Show only commits between the named two commits.
>   When either <since> or <until> is omitted, it defaults to HEAD, i.e. the tip of
>   the current branch.

`git log` needs a point (or points) to start from, so when no revision is provided, it defaults to `HEAD`, which points to current branch.

Comment: Thanks @max.  After seeing your answer, I've now edited my question by adding more details and examples. I hope the way I've framed the question now will enable you to answer it with the detail that I'm looking for.  :-)